# NodeJS: can you pass a variable to 'require'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**EDIT:** *to be clear, the code below has been simplified to focus on the problem at hand. I do know that `window` does not "exist" in Node. This code is in fact used with `jsdom` for offline rendering (and as such `window` IS available in my context).*

I need to `require` a module that must have access to two variables to load: `window` and `document`.
I am new to Node and I am probably missing something regarding variables' scope. I thought an inner function had access to the outer function's parameters. So here is the mechanism I used (I know this code does not make much sense like this, but I tried to extract the "idea" from actual code):

```
var t = function(window, document){
  var Chart = require('chart.js');
}

var t2 = function(){
  var window = {};
  var document = {};
  t(window, document);
}

t2();
```

But it does not work. `window` and `document` are undefined when `chart.js` loads.
I need to declare `window` and `document` as globals to make it work:

```
window = null;
document = null;

var t = function(window, document){
  var Chart = require('chart.js');
}

var t2 = function(){
  t(window, document);
}

t2();
```

But it's probably bad.

How is this done "properly"? Please note I can't modify the chart.js module itself.

Comment: If you're using a bundler and not doing server side rendering you don't need to explicitly pass `window` or any of its properties, they will be globally available at the time the code is executed (in the browser, not in node)

Comment: You need to use `window` in NodeJS?

Comment: are you sure window and document is needed in nodejs

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I simplified my example too much. I did it because I wanted to focus on the problem itself (passing variables to require).
In the actual code, `chart.js` is used with `jsdom` to do some offline rendering. So I do need `window` and it is available through `jsdom`.

Comment: your question is more about passing variables to callbacks than commonjs i think

Answer (score 2):

> can you pass a variable to 'require'?

No.

> I am new to Node and I am probably missing something regarding variables' scope. I thought an inner function had access to the outer function's parameters.
>
> ```
> var t = function(window, document){
>   var Chart = require('chart.js');
> }
>
> var t2 = function(){
>   var window = {};
>   var document = {};
>   t(window, document);
> }
>
> t2();
> ```

It does, but the code you're bringing in via require *isn't* in the `t` or `t2` function above.

While you *could* create global `window` and `document` properties before doing the `require`:

```
global.window = /*...*/;
global.document = /*...*/;
```

...that would be a Bad Thing™ on two levels:

1. Your `require` call isn't necessarily the one that loads the `chart.js` module.
2. Globals are, you know, icky. That's the technical term.

**Instead**, have `chart.js` expose an initialization function. Then you get that, call it with the required dependencies, and you're all set.

---

Note: NodeJS has no UI. If you're trying to do some kind of offline rendering, you may need a full headless browser like PhantomJS or similar, rather than NodeJS.

Comment: Thanks T.J.! `chart.js` is not my lib. As such (I mean I'd rather not have to "touch" it), how do I make it expose an initialisation function?
On your second point: I am using jsdom. It seems to work well and it has the advantage (I think) to be simpler to setup and use from within Node vs PhantomJS.

Comment: @PJC: I dont think you can. Fairly sure you want to be loading `chart.js` *via* jsdom, [like they do here with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601289/jsdom-and-document-ready), not via NodeJS's `require`.

Comment: OK, yes. It's what I am doing and it works fine. I was just concerned by the fact I had to expose these two "global" variables but I think I can actually keep them inside a module that will itself handle all this (loading jsdom, chart.js, etc).

Comment: @PJC: Yup. If you use `var` (they aren't in the question linked, which is pretty poor practice), they'll be scoped just to your module, so no globals created.