# JS: Difference in composed string to direct string for required

Tags: node.js, string, react-native

I'm trying to programatically require the language file necessary for translation.

```
let languageCode = "zh";
require(`./translations/${languageCode}.json`)
  or
require('./translations/'+languageCode+'.json')
```

It gives me error

```
Requiring unknow module "./translations/zh.json"
```

But this line would not give me any problem

```
require('./translations/zh.json')
```

Anyone have any clue? Seems very weird

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377332/nodejs-can-you-pass-a-variable-to-require

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* that you cannot pass variables or template strings to the `require` statement. I tried passing a variable to `require`, it did not work. So IMO, you have to pass a string literal.